# Creating a custom installation CD with LAMP stack and some other packages preinstalled

Tags: installation, remastersys

We produce an office automation tool (PHP+MySQL) and we install it on the customer's server machine (Ubuntu 11.04). Now is there a way to produce an Ubuntu installation CD that automatically installs the base OS + packages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a manual on the help sites on how to [customize the Ubuntu Install CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization). Try to follow that guide, it says it applies to the server version as well as the client version (alternative CD).

Good luck :)

Comment: Preseeding extra packages is easy, and explained well on that page.